# Change ItemTemplate of XAML Listview programmatically in backend

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, windows-10-universal

I've read so many postings here on StackOverflow and lots of blog entries but could not find a working answer to my question:
I'm developing a windows 10 universal app. I have a listview using an item template. Now I added another item template and want to set with template to use when the application starts. No need to do it item by item, the template should be added for all items.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
        (...)
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate2">
        (...)
    </DataTemplate>

</Page.Resources>

<ListView
        x:Name="itemListView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsListView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
        TabIndex="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        IsSwipeEnabled="False" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        SelectionChanged="ItemListView_SelectionChanged" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding FeedItems}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}" Margin="0,60,0,10" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

What's the easiest way to do it? I've tried so many options, none of them did work :-(
Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `ItemTemplate` in code behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    itemListView.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["DataTemplate2"];
}
```

Comment: When I read your answer I thought: Yes, I already tried that..... but obviously I did not :-( 
Your answer is brillant, thanks a lot!

Comment: I have created in code behind (c#) the Grid and inside Rows and Columns and then inside that rows/columns also created and put the Border and Text controls. Now I want to put this grid in DataTemplate in Code behind and then assign that DataTemplate to Listview ItemTemplate. So how it be possible . plz.

Here you have mentioned assigning DT to ItemTemplate but it gets from Resource ... and I have a dynamic values .. so I need to create it dynamic and put/set values.

Answer (score 0):

bit old question but first in google search, so , i add my answer
you may access template by name 
define x:name for resource

```
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="dtPerMeal" x:Name="dtPerMeal">
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Product.Name}" Detail="{Binding TotalWeight}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="dtPerBatch" x:Name="dtPerBatch">
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Product.Name}" Detail="0" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

and then access it by name in code behind
(switching datatemplate on a radiobutton change )

```
    private void rbMeal_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        lvProducts.ItemTemplate = (rbMeal.IsChecked) ? dtPerMeal : dtPerBatch;
    }
```